# PHP Manual - .chm file is not working

Tags: php, chm, manual

I just downloaded php_manual.en.chm file from https://www.php.net/download-docs.php
But Its not working.

Whenever i open this file then i see following Message:

Navigation to the webpage was canceled

What you can try:

```
 Retype the address.
```

(I am using Windows 7)

I searched a lot but i did not get exact solution for this. So please Guide me in that case.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: which OS you are using? on windows it will open properly.

Comment: Well, I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The help file is being blocked from opening by windows, you should be able to unblock it by:

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Find your CHM file
3. Right click and select
4. Properties Click the Unblock button on the General tab

There are some more details and options in [this Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902225).

Comment: Wow, Awesome. It worked. Thank you so much.
Your Answer was very Helpful for me.

Thanks once again :)

Comment: Darn it! Could have never figured this out had it not been for your comment!! Thanks a ton!!!!